# Using HTTrack to download links only under a certain subdomain (nothing external)

Tags: web, download, httrack

So, this is what I am trying to download - https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781337624183-calculus-9th-edition/

Looks fairly simple, I tried adding a few lines to "scan rules" to force it to download everything under it but for some reason, the entire process finishes under 10 seconds and it doesn't go further than just downloading the aforemention link itself.
For example, in addition to having https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781337624183-calculus-9th-edition/ itself, I would like to have all links originating from it, such as https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781337624183-calculus-9th-edition/311/ too.
Essentially, everything that starts with the first link above (including embedded pictures originating from other domains, but no external links.
As far as I know, adjusting a few settings and adding some rules to the "Scan Rules" section is supposed to do the trick, but I couldn't figure it out myself unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

In order to only copy links that are from that host and no other, to include the first link you submit you would need to setup scan rules.

On the menu page that you set the web address click the "Set options ..." button and then the Scan Rules tab.  Next ensure your scan rules exclude all links, and then that they include the links from the source you want.  And example of such a setup would be

```
+*.png +*.gif +*.jpg +*.jpeg +*.css +*.js -ad.doubleclick.net/* -mime:application/foobar
-*
+*[name].slader.com/*
```

This would essentially save all links originating from slader.com but would not store anything outside of that domain.

**EDIT**

If you only want links that begin with the link you typed in your scan rules would look similar to this:

```
+*.png +*.gif +*.jpg +*.jpeg +*.css +*.js -ad.doubleclick.net/* -mime:application/foobar
-*
+*[name].*[name]https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781337624183-calculus-9th-edition/*[name].*[name]/*
```

**EDIT**

You may not be able to get the other pages such as "Four Ways to Represent a Function" through HTTrack due to the way that specific sight has it's links structured.  If you look at the source their links are posted like:

```
<tr data-url="/textbook/9781337624183-calculus-9th-edition/17/" class="exercise-group">
                  <td>1.1</td>
                  <td style="width: 360px;">Four Ways to Represent a Function</td>
                  <td style="width: 230px;">Exercises</td>
                  <td style="width: 74px;">p.17</td>
                </tr>
```

As you can see they are using the data-url attribute to locate the next page utilizing a JS library to actually navigate the browser there.  As this is not an anchor tag HTTrack doesn't know that it's suppose to follow it as it doesn't see it as a link.

Some alternatives would be to use something like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) or [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) to write a web-scraper with your own rules that would better understand it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. This actually managed to eliminate other links that I didn't want the software to download, but it did not unfortunately go into the subdirectories of the main link I wanted. I did not alter any other setting except adding to the scan rules what you showed in the last part of your answer. Is there a way to "force" the software to download all the links under the main category?
Much appreciated

Comment: Do you mean such as 

https://.../9781337624183-calculus-9th-edition/ 
https://.../9781337624183-calculus-9th-edition/311/ 

Or were you talking about something else?  I'm sorry just trying to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. I meant the direct subcategories of the main link such as 

 https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781337624183-calculus-9th-edition/311/

 
https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781337624183-calculus-9th-edition/311/exercises/1b/

Essentially, anything that contains the main link + something else, such as:

https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781337624183-calculus-9th-edition/SOMETHING...

Comment: Well, I added the text on the edit to the "Scan Rules", unfortunately it did not go to the subdirectories as I mentioned already.

Comment: I see, I edited my answer again to explain why you're having difficulties

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221383/discussion-between-dccoder-and-evilracehorse).